# Facelets template reuse with conditionally displayed components

Tags: templates, jsf, facelets, reusability

How could I reuse the included jsf template that would display more/less data

For example I have main.xhtml which includes the child.xhtml

child.xhtml as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">
<body>
<h:outputText value="One"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="Two"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="Three"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="Four"></h:outputText>
</body>
</html>
```

The current implementation of child.xhtml displays "One","Two","Three" and "Four". I want to include the above child.xhtml somewhere else where it should only display "Two" and "Four".

Comment: Pass a `<ui:param>` in the including page and use it in `rendered` attribute of desired components in the included page. You can find many usage examples if you look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not a valid include file syntax. You're duplicating XML prolog, HTML doctype, `<html>` and `<body>` tags. This would only end up as [illegal](http://validator.w3.org) HTML syntax in the final output in webbrowser.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:outputText value="One" />
    <h:outputText value="Two" />
    <h:outputText value="Three" />
    <h:outputText value="Four" />
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

Coming back to your concrete question, in order to conditionally render the components, just make use of `rendered` attribute. You can parameterize it by passing an `<ui:param>` to `<ui:include>`.

E.g.

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:outputText value="One" rendered="#{empty hide or not hide}" />
    <h:outputText value="Two" />
    <h:outputText value="Three" rendered="#{empty hide or not hide}" />
    <h:outputText value="Four" />
</ui:composition>
```

which can be used as

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/client.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="hide" value="#{true}" />
</ui:include>
```

When `<ui:param name="hide">` is omitted, or its value is not `true`, then they will be shown.